# .htaccess mod_rewrite [P] for https

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/social/retrievePage.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/social/retrievePage.php?page=%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
</ifModule>
```

Basically it will remap any page to `https://www.example.com/social/retrievePage.php` and pass `REQUEST_URI` as `page` `GET` parameter.

It works well, however when I set `SSL` certificate for my domain, this will not work as expected, instead of remapping it will make a `301 Redirect`

I tried fixing the issue by replacing `http` to `https` from `RewriteRule`, got `500 Internal Server Error`.

What could be the issue?